# Create a Database on DB2 on Linux

Tags: db2

I have just instally successfully db2 on my linux machine, but I am not able to create a database.
When I make `CREATE DATABASE ABC;` I get the error that I haven't the authorization to create it...how can I get this authorization?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general tech support. Try the DBA site.

Comment: What login did you use to install DB2? (Hint: should be root.) What login are you using when creating the database? (Hint: should **not** be root.)

Comment: during the installation I let all the default options. The problem is while in mysql i use "mysql -u root -p" to connect to the root account to create a database here I can't understand how i can connect to the root account

Comment: DB2 is way too complicated to set up and use without having one or more books handy, in addition to the IBM manuals.  Go and find those books.

Comment: Again, you **should not** use root to work with DB2. Switch to the instance owner account you have provided when installing DB2 (probably `db2inst1`). As for books, the one you need is this: [Getting Started With DB2 Express-C](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/Big%20Data%20University/page/FREE%20eBook%20-%20Getting%20Started%20with%20DB2%20Express-C)

Answer (score 2):

When you install DB2, you most probably use the root user of the Linux server. 
Then in installing phase, you provide a user which will have the SYSADM and DBADM rights. That means DB2 creates a user which has all rights on the database(database admin).

So, after installation, you have to switch to that user to have rights to create a new database.
Depending on the version you installed, that username might be changed. But DB2 uses db2inst1 by default as administrator user.

Check your /home directory. You will see a new user(most probably db2inst1). Then switch to that user with:

```
su - db2inst1
```

then issue:

```
db2 CREATE DATABASE ABC
```

Let me know if you have a problem, also please provide your /home directory and the error message you get.

Answer (score -1):

You can check details of create db command and related authorization required here on DB2 Info Center:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001941.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-5-2-4-21&lang=en

As said above, this should work if you login as instance user. Most of times you do not need root access with DB2.

Comment: Could You please elaborate more, not just drop some kind of offsite resource? ...witch also appears to be broken.

`Our apologies… The page you requested cannot be displayed`

Comment: Link is correct but server is experiencing problems. Userid needs to have SYSADM or SYSCTRL authority in order to create a database. The instance userid will have this by default so you can use that to create the database, so ie if you are root and instance userid is db2inst1, do: su - db2inst1, then issue db2 create db command